# get a boolean into a checkbox from a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, boolean

Im trying to get values clicking on datagrid...I got the values from textobox and combobox...but when Im trying to get a value from a boolean the form doesnt work...

```
  private void dtg_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dtg.CurrentRow != null)
        {
            txtId.Text = dtg.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
            txtCode.Text = dtg.CurrentRow.Cells["CODE"].Value.ToString();
            //BOOLEAN
            ckbActive.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dtg.CurrentRow.Cells["ACTIVE"].ToString());
```

What I need is get the value on "ACTIVE" column in ckbActive form Control...

Comment: What do you get in `dtg.CurrentRow.Cells["ACTIVE"].ToString()`? I think some exception is coming because of `ckbActive.Checked` is not updated.

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid boolean...at System.Boolean.Parse(String value)

Comment: @LaloohFloresCruz: Well, what were a few such invalid boolean strings?

Comment: what is the value in `dtg.CurrentRow.Cells["ACTIVE"].ToString()`? Looks like you need to write your own method to convert `dtg.CurrentRow.Cells["ACTIVE"].ToString()` to Boolean.

Comment: what you see is my whole code...Im saving on "ACTIVE" a value, true or false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `ToString()` directly on the cell gets you the name of the type of column *(i.e. "DataGridViewTextBoxCell" or similar),* which can't be converted to a valid boolean:

```
ckbActive.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dtg.CurrentRow.Cells["ACTIVE"].ToString());
```

The actual value of the cell is accessible through the `Value` property, so use this instead:

```
ckbActive.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dtg.CurrentRow.Cells["ACTIVE"].Value);
```

Comment: Great...just changed the "ToString" instead "Value"...Now its working good